# Could I use gwt GUI in common java application?

Tags: java, swing, gwt, user-interface

I would like to use Google Web Toolkit's GUI in common java application instead of Swing. How could I implement that? Could anybody show the simpliest example how to do this?

Comment: If you handle javascript - why not? But you can use gwt/json services.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I would like to use Google Web Toolkit's GUI in common java application instead of Swing.

No. That's not the way [`how GWT works`](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-doc-1-5/wiki/FAQ_HowGWTWorks). GWT's java GUI code [`compiles`](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/compile.html) to JavaScript and runs in Browser.

So the answer is No.